# How to add multi-color text in R when working with viewports

Tags: r, shiny, grid, viewport

[image]I am trying to add multi color text in a title in one of our plots.

I have a grid layout that has one viewport, I am using gridtext as it makes it easy to add html and style the text, however I am not able to place it in the existing viewport.

Can you let me know how would I be able to do that?

```
titleFunction <- function() {
  
  library(ggplot2)
  library(gridExtra)
  library(grid)
  library(gridtext)
  
  textSizeMajor = 36
  textSizeMinor = 32
  
  mainLO <- grid.layout(nrow = 4, ncol = 3,
                        widths = unit(c(textSizeMajor * 1.2, 1, .5),
                                      c("points", "null", "cm")),
                        heights = unit(c(textSizeMajor, textSizeMajor, 40, 1),
                                       c("points", "points", "points", "null")))
  
  pushViewport(viewport(name="mainViewPort", layout = mainLO))
  
  
  fontface = "bold"
  

  # Main title
  grid.text("Main Title",
            vp = viewport(layout.pos.col = 2, layout.pos.row = 1),
            gp=gpar(fontsize=26, fontface = fontface))
  
  browser()

  grid.draw(richtext_grob(text = '<span style="color:red">Hello</span>, <span style="color:blue">World</span>!'))
  # Want to place this below Main title, where row = 2
  # vp = viewport(layout.pos.col = 2, layout.pos.row = 2)


  # main viewport pop
  popViewport(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was dealing with the grid and textGrob objects. Here is the code that works

```
print(grid.draw(richtext_grob(text = subTitle,
                                gp = gpar(fontsize=22),
                                vp = viewport(layout.pos.col = 2, layout.pos.row = 2))) )
```